# Youtube API missing field

Tags: youtube-api

I have problem getting statistics information from youtube data api. I make a request to http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=video_id&alt=json, it works for some, but for some video id, the response does not contain 'entry', 'yt$statistics', 'gd$rating' for example:

```
zLcbznigfs missing 'entry', aVfN6XjACDY missing 'yt$statistics', fjhQ9Kf4iHk missing 'gd$rating'
```

Comment: The field seems to be present in the feed.
`"yt$statistics": {     "favoriteCount": "215",     "viewCount": 67476"    }`

Answer (score 0):

After moving around, i found out the solution for this: use `&alt=atom` instead of using `&alt=json`, which means that we better read from Atom feed than JSON (and feedparser is an excellent module for doing this). I have checked this with several video id, it works fine.

Hope that help. Thanks.